# kdeinit5 crashes while taking screenshot

Tags: segmentation-fault

When i try to take screenshot and save it, kdeinit5 crashes because of segmentation fault.
Here is backtrace:

```
Application: kdeinit5 (kdeinit5), signal: Segmentation fault
    
[KCrash Handler]
#4  0x00007f36253eb566 in __memmove_avx_unaligned_erms () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#5  0x00007f36262bd492 in ?? () from /usr/lib/qt/plugins/kf5/kio/thumbnail.so
#6  0x00007f36217ee6ef in KIO::SlaveBase::dispatch(int, QByteArray const&) () from /usr/lib/libKF5KIOCore.so.5
#7  0x00007f36217ef016 in KIO::SlaveBase::dispatchLoop() () from /usr/lib/libKF5KIOCore.so.5
#8  0x00007f36262bb026 in kdemain () from /usr/lib/qt/plugins/kf5/kio/thumbnail.so
#9  0x000055aff48775bd in ?? ()
#10 0x000055aff4878a59 in ?? ()
#11 0x000055aff4879237 in ?? ()
#12 0x000055aff4874b54 in ?? ()
#13 0x00007f36252aeb25 in __libc_start_main () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#14 0x000055aff48756be in ?? ()
[Inferior 1 (process 1113043) detached]
`
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar bug. This is reported [here](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=430862) and will be fixed in KDE Frameworks version 5.81. For your info the current version is 5.80.0. The version with bug fix will be released on 10 April 2021 according to [this](https://community.kde.org/Schedules/Frameworks) source.

Sources: [Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/mlubed/kdeinit_closes_unexpectedly/)
[KDE bug report](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=430862)
[KDE release report](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=430862)